# Company-mode slow in ESS

Tags: company-mode, ess

When using (i)ESS, I would like to function/variable/argument/filename completion on demand using the minibuffer, without triggering the company pseudotooltip front end.

I have tried the following:

```
(setq company-begin-commands nil)
      company-idle-delay nil)
```

This seems to work fine for all sorts of completion. Except, that when I call a function that has a lot of arguments, emacs becomes very unresponsive. For example, if I type:

```
print(
```

and press `TAB` after the parenthesis, the minibuffer will show, but typing will become nearly impossible (i.e. delay of 2 or 3 seconds between each typed character). Even if I disable `company-mode` the completion is sluggish so I wonder if this is an issue of ESS? How to solve this?

Comment: any luck with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There's been a recent development that might solve the issue for people in the future.

It turns out that the contextual help at the bottom in the minibuffer that appears when you're getting autocomplete is massively inefficient. This seems to be an isolated issue when `company-mode` is on. The current "fix" is a flag someone put into a very recent version of ESS.

You can enable it by setting `(setq ess-r--no-company-meta t)`.

You'll still get completion from `company-mode`. The only difference is that the sometimes helpful, sometimes not, line in the minibuffer that will say `plot(x, y, main="", etc., ...)` will not appear.

See the [discussion](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/1062) on GitHub.